# Show Ribbon always to Visitors

Tags: ribbon

Is there any way to show Ribbon for visitors, in all pages, by default?

**Normal Page View for Visitors:** (No Ribbon)

[image]

**Normal Page for Editors:**

[image]

I am looking for a solution to display the ribbon for Visitors by default (even though only alertme and Email a Link will be enabled)

**Editor's view of Page with Web Parts :**
[image]

**Editor's view of Page with Web Parts when a webpart is selected :**

[image]

**Visitors View of the page with Multiple Web Parts** (No Ribbon)
[image]

As you can see even if I select the Web Part, Ribbon will not be displayed.

Ribbon will be shown if the visitor visits the document library page. For example
[image]

I am looking for a solution by which I can display the ribbon always for all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Used [`Ribbon.CommandUIVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.commandui.ribbon.commanduivisible.aspx) property. I wrote code to set its value as `True` for everypage load.

```
public void ShowRibbon()
{
    SPRibbon current = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);

    if (current != null && this.Page.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        current.CommandUIVisible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, i didnt know of that property. Will check it out

Answer (score 3):

What would you like the ribbon to show, when clicking the web parts?

What i'm trying to say is that the ribbon depends on context. If you have the appropriate rights, it will show you Item and List tabs in a list, but only when you are on the list forms pages, since that is the context that triggers the ribbon to show.

When looking at Xml List view web parts representing lists and libraries, you do not get a ribbon, unless you are in edit mode or clicked "Show Ribbon" from Site Actions (and this button only shows up if you enabled "Show Ribbon" in  `http://yourSite/_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx`). When you **do** see the ribbon, what you see will again depend on context: if you are in edit mode and select a row in a list view web part, you will see `Web Part Tools > Options`, `Page Tools > Insert` and `List Tools > Items | List`.

If you are on a published page you should only see List Tools > Items | List` which i guess is the one you want? Just remember that you need to click on the list item to get the ribbon, since it works in context of what you select.

what team site looks like for visitor at login
[image: what team site looks like for visitor at login]
visitor click web part chrome[image: visitor click web part chrome]
visitor click list item
[image: visitor click list item]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited my question to include screenshots. Please check.

Comment: are you talking anonymous users or readers?

Comment: the behaviour seems consistent with that someone disabled ribbon. When i log into a site with a reader, i see the ribbon. Did you check the ribbon setting (publishing site only) `http://yourSite/_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx`

Comment: Above link activates 'show/hide' ribbon menu item. If you see my screenshots, visitor does not have Site Actions Menu. Another thing to note is.. 1) I give a visitor more rights and 2) enables ribbon using show/hide ribbon command. 3) I remove his rights and revert back to Visitor ..... and the visitor still sees the ribbon (with buttons disabled as per permission) :)

Comment: What happens behind the scenes when "show/hide ribbon" is clicked? Any ideas?

Comment: This is not the behaviour i see when i log in as visitor/reader (see updated post).

Comment: Do you see Site Actions when loggin in as a visitor? I see Site Actions in your screenshot.

Comment: I am using Publishing Template... Let me check a Team Site. Thanks

Comment: to answer your question on what happens when you click the button: Reflector reveals that the Ribbon behaviour is controlled by a property value in AllProperties on SPWeb: `"__DisplayShowHideRibbonActionId"` that is set to true/false

Comment: Team Site pages reside in "Site Pages" library and these are application pages. I am looking for Pages in "pages" library

Comment: the Test visitor user is member of Test Visitor group that has read permission. I *do* see Site Actions, but all it contains is "View all site content"

Comment: setting __DisplayShowHideRibbonActionId property is same as setting http://yourSite/_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx  :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1628/discussion-between-anders-rask-and-shoban)

Comment: Got it working! :) I have posted my answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether I have understood your requirement clearly, but hope this post helps - http://danielvg.dk/post/2010/07/11/SharePoint-Show-Ribbon-by-Default.aspx

Comment: Thanks Deepu. This is not what I am looking for :-)