# How to force showing the ribbon accross my enterprise wiki pushing site

Tags: page-layout, publishing-site, ribbon, publishing-page, site-settings

One of the problems I am facing inside my enterprise wiki publishing site , is that the ribbon is hidden by default, and to be able to display it I need to click on the gear image, and then click on show ribbon.

[image]

So is there a way to always show the ribbon on the page?

Thanks

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54367/ribbon-gets-hidden-by-default-how-to-fix-that

Answer (score 0):

Site setting -> Navigation -> Show and Hide Ribbon Setting Make "Show Ribbon" and "Hide Ribbon" commands available to No